# Find XML file changes in all branches

Tags: tfs

I have an XML file in my main TFS branch. I have 50 branches of the main folder. Is there a quick way to check in which branches the file is modified before merging it to the main branch?

I have found that it can be done with CodeLens for code files, but I don't know how to do it for XML files.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to these steps below:

1. Create a new workspace
2. Map these branches (Do not include other mapping)
3. To do work (e.g. modify files)
4. Open Team Explorer
5. Switch to this workspace

[image]

6. Click Pending Changes, then all changes in this workspace will be list.

If these changes are already existing in different workspace, you can check in changes through TFS API (install [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/14.102.0) to your project).

Simple code to iterate all workspaces in a machine and check in specified changes:

```
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("[username]", "[password]", "[domain]");
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("[collection url"), cred);
            tpc.EnsureAuthenticated(); 
VersionControlServer versionControl = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>(); 
             var spaces = versionControl.QueryWorkspaces(null, null, "[machine name, can be null]");
            foreach(var currentWorkspace in spaces)
            {
               var libChanges= currentWorkspace.GetPendingChanges("[server or local path]",RecursionType.Full);
                if (libChanges.Count() > 0)
                {
                    currentWorkspace.CheckIn(changes: libChanges, comment: "checkInAPI");
                }
            }
```

Update:

You can compare branches.

1. Open Source Control Explorer
2. Right click a branch > Compare
3. Change Target path to target branch server path
4. Click OK.

On the other hand, there is an [TFS Productivity Pack extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShiningDragon.TFSProductivityPack) you can use.

Comment: The file has already been changed in the branches, this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: @hectorct For this scenario, the better way is to check in changes through TFS API (Check my update).

Comment: I think I haven't stated it clearly, sorry. The changes are already commited to to the branches, there are no pending changes. I want to know what branches have changes that are not merged to the main branch.

Comment: @hectorct Ok, for this scenario, you need to compare branches, not found the quick way.